# Unable to change the current elements class using nativeElement in ngFor Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, ng-bootstrap

I want to change add or remove active class using nativeElement.
I'm having a label inside a for loop and want to add/remove class.
Since its in a loop and im fetching element using #someid it always reflect on 1st index element.

Html:-

```
    <div *ngFor="let object of someList; index as i ; trackBy:trackById">
       <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle " ngbRadioGroup name="{{i}}" (ngModelChange)="statusChanged($event,object)" 
[ngModel]="object.boolean">
          <label #truelabel ngbButtonLabel class="btn-outline-danger btn-sm mb-0">
          <input ngbButton type="radio" class="invisible" [value]="true">true
          </label>
          <label #falselabel ngbButtonLabel class="btn-outline-danger btn-sm mb-0">
          <input ngbButton type="radio" class="invisible" [value]="false">false
          </label>
       </div>
    </div>
```

MyComponent:-

```
@ViewChild('truelabel') truelabel;
@ViewChild('falselabel') falselabel;
statusChanged($event,object){
    var action = "";
    if ($event) {
      action = "trueElement";
    } else {
      action = "falseElement";
    }
    swal({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      text: "You want to change the status?",
      type: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      allowOutsideClick: false,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
      cancelButtonText: 'No',
      confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success ml-2',
      cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger mr-2',
      buttonsStyling: false,
      reverseButtons: true
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        //some thing
        swal(
          'Done',
          'changed successfully',
          'success'
        )
      } else if (
        // Read more about handling dismissals
        result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.cancel
      ) {
        swal(
          'Cancelled',
          'Request has been cancelled',
          'error'
        )
        if (action == 'trueElement') {
          if (this.truelabel.nativeElement.classList.value.indexOf('active') > -1) {
            this.truelabel.nativeElement.classList.remove('active');
            this.falselabel.nativeElement.classList.add('active');
          }
        }
      }
    })
}
```

On cancel, i want to reset the radio button back to its states, So I want to change the class programmatically using #someid and nativeElement.
Please suggest me how it can be achieved.

Comment: Have you tried document.querySelector('#someid') ?

Comment: is it helpful in for loop? Since Id will be duplicate, I'm unable to specify the selected element.

Comment: You should be able to just set your ngModel property to null but change ngModel to use two way binding by enclosing it in parenthesis as well

Comment: That was not a solution.. If I select 2nd index element button, so when I change the class of that element it changing always 1st index radiobutton.